# How to switch between async & sync in .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

How do I go about switching between async/sync processing of multiple tasks in C#?

I'd like to be able to switch between parallel and synchronous processing of tasks for testing/profiling purposes.

Initially I had an array of Tasks initialised inline. While this was fine for parallel, I found my synchronous code wouldn't work because each method would be activated on initialization of the array.

I decided to try Lazy instead. Is this code correct? If not, how is this best achieved?

```
  var runTasks = new Lazy<Task<ProcessWithResult>>[]
            {
                new Lazy<Task<ProcessWithResult>>(() => GetHeaderRecord()),
                new Lazy<Task<ProcessWithResult>>(() => GetChildType1Entities()),
                new Lazy<Task<ProcessWithResult>>(() => GetChildType2Entities()),
                new Lazy<Task<ProcessWithResult>>(() => GetChildType3Entities()),                     
            };

            if (Settings.Default.AsyncProcessing)
            {
                Task.WaitAll(runTasks.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());
            }
            else
            {
                // do these in sequence
                runTasks.ToList().ForEach(t => t.Value.Wait());
            }

            // carryon...
```

Each GetX() method signature is like so:

```
public async Task<ProcessWithResult> GetChildType1Entities()
```

With at least one async operation on Database or file i/o.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach could work, however i would avoid using Lazy for this.

There is a lazy language construct in C# already, it's yield return, and it would result in cleaner code:

```
public static class Runner
{
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<ProcessWithResult>> RunAll(this IEnumerable<Task<ProcessWithResult>> tasks, bool runSequentially)
    {
        if (!runSequentially) return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        var results = new List<ProcessWithResult>();
        foreach (var task in tasks)
            results.Add(await task);
        return results;
    }
}

public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void RunInParallel()
    {
        var results = GetAllTasks().RunAll(false).Result;
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 2, 1 }, results.OrderBy(r => r.WhenFinished).Select(r => r.Id));
    }

    [Test]
    public void RunInSequentially()
    {
        var results = GetAllTasks().RunAll(true).Result;
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 1, 2 }, results.OrderBy(r => r.WhenFinished).Select(r => r.Id));
    }

    IEnumerable<Task<ProcessWithResult>> GetAllTasks()
    {
        yield return RunTask(1, 1000);
        yield return RunTask(2, 100);
    }

    async Task<ProcessWithResult> RunTask(int id, int wait)
    {
        await Task.Delay(wait);
        return new ProcessWithResult {Id = id, WhenFinished = DateTime.Now};
    }
}

public class ProcessWithResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime WhenFinished { get; set; }
}
```

This way the method still runs asyncronously both in production and the tests.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have to digest this.  Apart from using inbuilt C# syntax is this the only reason for going for this approach?

Comment: As i noted already, the method is truly async, so it naturally fits in async pipeline and provides sequential execution at the same time, which is important, as you are not making any blocking calls as with 'Wait' and "WaitAll". Note that I'm using await and WhenAll. In your original call execution is blocking. In my example, it's blocking on the 'Result' property for the tests, but you can use await on the task in production both for the sequential and parallel cases.