# Easily switch between async and sync through the entire call stack (for debugging)

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Code using the `async` keyword is great for performance, but as anyone who has used it knows knows:

1) it's near-impossible to debug; and

2) it tends to "grow" through the entire codebase, all the way up to the main method

Often the sync and async versions of a method will differ only by calling the sync and async versions of another method.

Is there a way to easily switch between the async and sync versions of the code throughout the callstack (i.e. all methods from Main down to the one that calls some library method)?

I could of course do something like this:

```
        public static
#if NOASYNC
        void
#else
        async Task
#endif
        Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
#if NOASYNC
            string contents = MyMethod1(fileName);
#else
            string contents = await MyMethod1(fileName);
#endif
            Console.WriteLine(contents);
        }

        private static
#if NOASYNC
        string
#else
        async Task<string>
#endif
        MyMethod1(string fileName)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(fileName);
#if NOASYNC
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
#else
            return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
#endif
        }
```

but this is obviously a nightmare to write and maintain - and that contrived example is only 2 method deep. I could probably hack something using Reflection, too, but I'd like to avoid that, at least for the production (async) code path to keep the performance and type safety.

Note: the title is similar to [How to switch between async & sync in .NET/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32587640/how-to-switch-between-async-sync-in-net-c) but this is not a duplicate of that question, which is concerned with running one set of methods sync or async. I'm looking for a way to do this with the calling method and its calling methods, etc.

Comment: *This*, or something like it, is going to be *way* harder to debug than asynchronous code, which is nowhere near impossible to debug.  Heavily parallelized code is often hard to debug, whether synchronous or asynchronous, but sequential asynchronous code, particularly when using `await`, is not hard to debug at all.

Comment: Not hard in theory, but in practice I find that I can't just step in/step out of async methods like sync methods. Maybe it's just bugs in VS, but if they haven't been fixed by now they're not likely to be soon, so in practice I find I have to switch to sync code sometimes.

Comment: You're *way* more likely to introduce bugs trying to keep two separate implementations of your code side by side, and/or constantly radically changing how the code behaves, than you are occasionally running into edge cases in the VS debugger when doing unusual things while debugging.  And that's practical advice, not theoretical advice, from someone who's debugged plenty of asynchronous programs.

Comment: I think you have problems with debugging async code because it's written wrong. Most probably you are not awaiting async methods, or have async void methods, or mixing sync over async. Otherwise debugging async code is exactly same as sync one.

Comment: I am awaiting async methods and do not have async void methods. Mixing sync with async is sometimes unavoidable. OK, when I next run into a specific issue debugging async code I may post that as a separate question, but this question is still interesting and relevant to me.

Comment: @EM0 "Mixing sync with async is sometimes unavoidable" It's basically guaranteed to make sure that the program is buggy and that you're getting none of the benefits of using asynchrony while keeping all of the downsides and then some.  It's almost always avoidable, and *necessary* to avoid it in basically all situations, if you want to have a functioning program.